# Attempting to fashion (Google Sheets)...IF search within a range is true, COUNT all occurances of search in the range AND decrease by 1, if false, 0

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, countif

Example long hand formula:
IF "text_1" [a cell reference] appears in this range [a column range], COUNT all occurances of "text_1" in the range and decrease by 1, if "text_1" [the cell reference] does not appear, 0.

I've tried:  =countif(C$2:C$15,$A17)-1  YET, when A17 does not appear in C2:C15, the result is -1.  I need 0.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=MAX(COUNTIF(C2:C15, A17)-1, 0)
```

note that if there will be 1 match final result will be zero too

Comment: Thank you, player0!  You solved my problem and taught me the extensive use of MAX.  So much appreciation!